# Issue to pass data from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android

i need to iterate array and pass each item of array from activity to fragment; but with my code i pass to fragment from activity only the last item.

I hope that you can help me!

i show you my code!

ACTIVITY:

```
try {
                    JSONObject contacts = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = contacts.getJSONArray("pdfs");
                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                       // title_array.add(c.getString("title").toString());
                        url_pdf=c.getString("url_pdf");



                        SixFragment fragment =  new SixFragment();
                        fragment.setName(url_pdf);

                       /* Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("user", url_pdf);
                        SixFragment fragmentt = new SixFragment();
                        fragmentt.setArguments(bundle);
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.ah, fragmentt)
                                .commit();
*/

                    }

                    System.out.println("PDFSSSSSSS"+url_pdf);

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public class SixFragment  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
String url_pdf="";
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pdfList;
    HashMap<String, String> pdf;
    String data="";
    String arg="";
    static String azzzz="";
    public SixFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public void setName(String string){
        azzzz = string;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_six, container, false);


        /*Bundle bundle=getArguments();

        String pala=bundle.getString("user");*/

        pdfList = new ArrayList<>();

        HashMap<String, String> pdf = new HashMap<>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        pdf.put("id", azzzz);


        // adding contact to contact list
        pdfList.add(pdf);

        for (int i = 0; i < pdfList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("CONTAT:"+pdfList.size());
        }
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getContext(), pdfList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"id"}, new int[]{R.id.name});



        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;

    }
```

SIX_FRAGMENT.XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container_frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SixFragment">



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ah"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should get your data in an array, then you create your Fragment and pass the array in the fragment arguments, so the Fragment can get them when created. Or you create your Fragment, get the data in an array (in the Activity) and then update the Fragment with the array (by calling an "update" method on your Fragment)
But what you're doing at the moment is to create your Fragment at each loop of your "for"!

Comment: @Eselfar can you make me an example?please?

Comment: I have added an example below.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting url_pdf to fragment over and over again, but url_pdf is always holding just 1 value. You should create an Array , or a JsonObject and pass it as an Extra.

Activity;

```
try {
                JSONObject contacts = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray jsonArray = contacts.getJSONArray("pdfs");

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("user", list);
                SixFragment fragmentt = new SixFragment();
                fragmentt.setArguments(bundle);
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.ah, fragmentt)
                            .commit();


            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
```

Fragment:

```
public class SixFragment  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> list;

    ...
    public SixFragment getInstance(JSONArray json) {
        Bunble b = new Bundle();
        b.putExtra("JSON",json);
        SixFragment f = new SixFragment();
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstance = savedInstanceState != null;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        JSONArray jsonArray = getArguments.get("JSON");
        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            list.add(c.getString("url_pdf"));
            System.out.println("PDFSSSSSSS"+url_pdf);
        }
}
```

Comment: The Fragment should be set with the processed data as there is no value in processing the data in the Fragment.

Comment: You are right, just proccess the Json and pass your Object to the fragment

Comment: @Eselfar i added above also six fragment layout...it is correct for ".replace(R.id.ah, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())"?

Comment: @Markus Above is not my answer.

Comment: @Eselfar above in my question

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You can use Gson instead of parsing the JSON manually.

**In the Activity**

```
try {
    // Instantiate a new ArrayList to store the urls
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONObject contacts = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    JSONArray jsonArray = contacts.getJSONArray("pdfs");
    // looping through All Contacts
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String url_pdf = c.getString("url_pdf");

        // add the url to the array of 'url_pdf'
        urls.add(url_pdf);

        // Display each url retrieved (not necessary)
        System.out.println("PDFSSSSSSS" + url_pdf);
    }

    SixFragment fragment = SixFragment.newInstance(urls);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            // Replace the current Fragment. Use the Fragment class name as tag (can
            // be useful to find the fragment later)
            .replace(R.id.ah, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .commit();

} catch (final JSONException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**In the SixFragment**

```
private static final String ARGS_URLS = "bundle_urls";
private ArrayList<String> mUrls;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

public SixFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * @param urls ArrayList of url_pdf
 * @return A new instance of the {@link SixFragment}
 */
public static SixFragment newInstance(ArrayList<String> urls) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // put the array into the fragment arguments bundle
    args.putStringArrayList(ARGS_URLS, urls);

    SixFragment fragment = new SixFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Retrieve data from the Fragment's arguments
    mUrls = getArguments().getStringArrayList(ARGS_URLS);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_six, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Use an ArrayAdapter instead of the SimpleAdapter as it automatically manage a List
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUrls);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: i got this error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SixFragment.onCreate(SixFragment.java:58)"

Comment: can you help me, please?

Comment: You forgot to set the fragment's arguments, that why your bundle is null. In my example, in the activity, to create the SixFragment I do: SixFragment fragment = SixFragment.newInstance(urls). If you read the code of newInstance(...), I create a Bundle which contains the list of urls and I set it as the Fragment's arguments (fragment.setArguments(args)).

Comment: If you're not in a rush, I'll create a github project with my answer later today, like that you could see how it is implemented.

Comment: Yeah I understood that part. That why I want to provide you a full working example so like that you could download it and see how it's implemented.

Comment: @Markus Have a look at this project https://github.com/Eselfar/DataToFragmentExample

Comment: i got this error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SixFragment.onCreate(SixFragment.java:73)"

Comment: Have you tried to download and run my example?
How do you instantiate your SixFragment? Can you post your updated code?

Comment: url_pdf=c.getString("url_pdf");

                        urls.add(url_pdf);

    





                    }
                    SixFragment fragment =  new SixFragment();
                    fragment.setName(urls);" FRAGMENT:"public void setName( ArrayList<String> mUrls){
       murls = mUrls;
   }

Comment: i this way i pass arrayist to fragment but when i put array list into ArrayAdapter, sometimes app crash and sometimes app it ok...i don't know why.

Comment: Where is you "newSixFragment()" method? What does it do? 
You should put the ArrayList of urls in a Bundle, then instantiate your Fragment, set the Bundle as arguments (fragment.setArguments(Bundle)) and then replace the existing Fragment with this new one calling the supportFragmentManager as you can see in both Jonathan Aste and I examples.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry I misread. Should works that way too even if it's better to use a Bundle. You probably have an error somewhere else if the app crashes.

Comment: i don't know why but sometimes app crash and logical say me that size of adapter is null and sometimes it works...

Comment: What is the error exactly? It seems that you give a null array to your Adapter. Are you always testing with the same JSON or your data change?

Comment: so about adapter that reference a null object

Comment: when IDE give me error, if i comment array adapter code, in logical i see that mUrls ArrayList pass from activity to fragment...

Comment: Can you please update your post with your new code as it difficult to figure out what is happening without seen it?